# Two files using supertest with mocha causing EADDRINUSE

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, supertest

I'm using supertest to unit test my server configurations and route handlers. The server configurations tests are in `test.server.js` and the route handling tests are in `test.routes.handlers.js`.

When I run all the test files using `mocha .`, I get `EADDRINUSE`. When I run each file individually, everything works as expected.

Both files define and require supertest, `request = require('supertest')`, and the express server file, `app = require('../server.js')`. In `server.js`, the server is started like so:

```js
http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), config.hostName, function () {
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

Is there something wrong in my implementation? How can I avoid `EADDRINUSE` error when running my tests?

Comment: check that both file dont listen on the same port or mistakenly you have included app.listen in both file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

mocha has a [root Suite](http://visionmedia.github.io/mocha/):

`You may also pick any file and add "root" level hooks, for example add beforeEach() outside of describe()s then the callback will run before any test-case regardless of the file its in. This is because Mocha has a root Suite with no name.`

We use that to start an Express server once (and we use an environment variable so that it runs on a different port than our development server):

```
before(function () {
  process.env.NODE_ENV = 'test';
  require('../../app.js');
});
```

(We don't need a `done()` here because require is synchronous.) This was, the server is started exactly once, no matter how many different test files include this root-level `before` function.

Try requiring supertest from within a root level before function in each of your files.

Comment: After you require `app.js`, don't you need to pass the returned object to `supertest`? My understanding is that supertest needs to have your server as its first argument, i.e. `var request = require('supertest'); var app = require('../../app.js'); request = request(app);` and only then can you do `request.get('/')` or whatever. So how are you passing `app` to supertest in the other files? I guess I'm gonna try and make a unique global variable and pass that...

Comment: What worked for me is moving the `require` statements for supertest and app to the very top, outside `before` and `describe` in both files.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question:

My supertest initialization looks like this:

```
var app = require('../server.js');
var request = require('supertest')(app);
```

In `test.server.js`, I had these require statements directly inside a `describe`. In `test.routes.handlers.js`, the statements were inside a `before` inside a `describe`.

After reading [dankohn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18801551/two-files-using-supertest-with-mocha-causing-eaddrinuse#18802494), I was inspired to simply move the statements to the very top outside any `describe` or `before` and the tests all run without problems now.