# Testing Express Js Server using mocha and chai

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mocha.js, chai

I'm trying to test my express server using mocha and chai but i'm not able to close the server connection once the test has been completed.

Index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const dbconnection = require('./dbConnection.js');

const app = express();
.....

(async ()=>{
 await dbconnection.init();

/* Loading middleware and stuff */

 const server = app.listen(port, host, ()=>{
   console.log('Server Started!')
   app.emit('ready');
});
})()

module.exports = app;
```

I would like to know how to close the server once the test is executed. Currently testing is working but after the test it hangs.

server.test.js

```
const server = require("../../index");
const chai = require("chai");
const chaiHttp = require("chai-http");
const should = chai.should();
chai.use(chaiHttp);

before(function (done) {
  this.timeout(15000);
  server.on("ready", () => {
    done();
  });
});

describe.only("Health Check Test", function () {
  describe("/GET healthy", () => {
    it("it should GET the health status", (done) => {
      chai
        .request(server)
        .get("/healthy")
        .end((error, res) => {
          res.should.have.status(200);
          done();
        });
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're calling your anonymous async function. To fix this, you would need to not call it inline, and call it in another file:

```
// index.js
const app = express()

const startApp = async () => {
  await dbconnection.init();

  const server = app.listen(port, host, ()=>{
    console.log('Server Started!')
    app.emit('ready');
  });
}

module.exports = { app, startApp }

// server.test.js
const { app: server } = requre('../../')

// index.boot.js, or start.js, or something else
require('./index').startApp()
```

If you end up needing the database connection during tests, you would need to also lift that up out of the function that calls `app.listen` so you can close it in your tests.

Comment: How can i close the app? That is the problem..i cant call app.close

Comment: For the actual closing, you can either use `http.createServer` with `done`, or use `chai.request(server).close()` as in the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49789886/how-to-correctly-close-express-server-between-tests-using-mocha-and-chai).

Comment: If i call chai.request(server).close i think i will get 'not a function' exception. I guess .close is only available for what is returned from listener